# Find element exists in first array and not in second for dynamic arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays and the second array is like the following :

```
$array2 = ['android', 'iphone', 'windowsmobile'];
```

now the first array can be like either

```
$array1 = ['web', 'android', 'iphone'];
```

OR

```
$array1 = ['android']; // Not web
```

OR

```
$array1 = ['web', 'iphone']; // web+android
```

OR

```
$array1 = ['android', 'iphone'];
```

and never be `web` alone.

and `$array2` will be same always.

Now I need to check is there any element in the first array is not there in the second array and to get this value. In the first and third case it is `web` and for the second case there is nothing.

How this can be done ?

Comment: Now tell me, why not `array_diff`?

Comment: This might help https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: No. This will only show one directional difference

Comment: @HappyCoder Do one thing, besides that every dynamic $array1, write output you are expecting so that we will work as per that. Because, we still don't know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @HappyCoder You should really do what RahulMeshram says: Show us your expected output for every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php


$array2 = ['android', 'iphone', 'windowsmobile'];

$array1 = ['web', 'android', 'iphone'];
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));

$array1 = ['android']; // Not web
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));

$array1 = ['web', 'iphone']; // web+android
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));

$array1 = ['android', 'iphone'];
print_r(array_diff($array1, $array2));

?>
```

#### Output

> ```
> Array(
>  [0] => web
> )
> Array(
> )
> Array(
>  [0] => web
> )
> Array(
> )
> ```

[See it in action on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/r6u0o)